# How do I get a border around a component element ina canvas with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I'm creating a canvas with JS and then making a component in said canvas, and I want to have blue borders around the component. Can I do this with javascript or CSS?

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
<style>
canvas {
    border:1px solid #d3d3d3;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
</style>
</head>
<body onload="startGame()">
<script>

var myGamePiece;

function startGame() {
    myGameArea.start();
    myGamePiece = new component(30, 30, "red", 10, 120);
}

var myGameArea = {
    canvas : document.createElement("canvas"),
    start : function() {
        this.canvas.width = 480;
        this.canvas.height = 270;
        this.context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
        document.body.insertBefore(this.canvas, document.body.childNodes[0]);
    }
}

function component(width, height, color, x, y) {
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;    
    ctx = myGameArea.context;
    ctx.fillStyle = color;
    ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
}

</script>

<p>We have added a component to our game, a red square!</p>

</body>
</html>
```

This is a simplified version of the code. Its the component named myGamePiece that I'm trying to give a border.

Comment: You could use JS like `component = document.getElementById('component')` `component.style.border = '2px solid red'` If you can post your code I can probably give you a more detailed answer for your use case

Comment: Not quite sure how I respond with the code in a comment, but I edited the original post with some of the code. Thank you for the tip, might try this if I cant find a another way around the issue.

Comment: No worries, I posted an answer with a modified version of your component function

Answer (score 0):

Can achieve a border using `stroke()`

```
function component(width, height, color, x, y) {
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;    
    ctx = myGameArea.context;
    ctx.rect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
    ctx.fillStyle = color;
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.lineWidth = 2;
    ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
    ctx.stroke();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are developing game, the color property you might want to change based on your game logic. It better to use JavaScript for this.

Insert below lines before - `ctx.fillStyle = color;` It should work fine.

```
ctx.strokeStyle = 'blue';
ctx.strokeRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
```

Here is code for the same - https://codepen.io/viveksonkar19n/pen/LYZXeEP

Answer (score -1):

```
document.getElementById('your-component').style.border = 'parameters';
```

you can change background, text-color, etc. by just adding the correct words after style in that snippet. Alternately, you could do

```
.your-component {
border-style: solid;
border-color: blue;
}
```

in css